# How to increase multiple cell height by percentage in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, alignment

I have a table with different vertical heights like 20, 30 and 40. The heights are arranged by autofit.
The problem is that the cells are very close to each other.
I want to give a space at the top and the bottom.
I tried vertical alignment but could not add a space between cells.
It would be great if there is a percentage increase of multiple cell like from 20,30,40 to 22,33, 44. 10%
Or it would be also great if there is a constant increase like from 20,30, 40 to 22, 32, 42. 2 constant

Comment: You can create a macro which performes this.

Answer (score 1):

*VBA (Macro) can slove your problem:*

```
Sub Setrowheight()

    Dim hgt As Variant
    Dim WorkRng As Range

    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address

    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Please select the height range:", "Row Height", xTxt, , , , , 8)

For Each H In WorkRng
        If H.Value > 15 Then
            hgt = H.Value
            H.EntireRow.Select
            Selection.rowheight = hgt
        End If
    Next H
End Sub
```

[image]

---

[image]

---

**How it works:**

- Inset values in appropriate cell of Col A.
- Either **Right Click** the Sheet Tab and from poped up menu hit **View Code** or Press **Alt+F11** to get VB editor.
- On top left find **Project Explorer**, select the **Sheet Tab** then **Right Click** and hit **Insert** then **Module**.
- **Copy** & **Paste** this code.
- **RUN** the Macro.
- Select Range `A12:A17` to respond the **Input Box** & finish with **Ok**

*You find the corresponding Row's height has been set using Cell values in `A12:A17`.*

**N.B.**

- Standard Row height is `15.00` therefore insert values in `A12:A17`considering that to increase or even decrease the Row height.
- You may adjust the cell references as needed.